# how to introduce flyway into spring-boot project using h2 database and yaml properties?

Tags: spring-boot, properties, yaml, h2, flyway

I am trying to integrate flyway library into the spring-boot project using h2 and yaml properties. Unfortunately while starting the application I did not receive any logs that the Flyway is started and also I cannot see the table under the h2-console. (I see another tables created by hibernate)

This is my code:

*pom.xml*

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0</version>
</plugin>
```

*application.yml*

```
spring:
    h2:
        console:
            enabled: true
            path: /h2-console
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:file:~/testdb
        username: sa
        password:
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    jpa:
        hibernate.ddl-auto: none
        show-sql: true
    flyway:
        enabled: true
        locations: filesystem:/db/migration
```

*V1_0__init.sql* under src/main/resources/db/migration

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_USERS (ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, USERID VARCHAR(45));
INSERT INTO USERS (ID, USERID) VALUES (1, 'TEST.com');
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: What is the maven command u are using ? (Coz I see u are using the maven plugin and not the dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To automatically run Flyway database migrations on startup, you should add flyway dependency in your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

2. Add your db migrations in application.yml:

```
  flyway:
    locations: classpath:/db/migration
```

Then youshould see flyway logs on startup.

For more informations:
[10.6.1. Execute Flyway Database Migrations on Startup](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-execute-flyway-database-migrations-on-startup)